# python, how to handle event between multiple windows?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm using the following sample code to generate two windows:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Demo1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'New Window', width = 25, command = self.new_window)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
    def new_window(self):
        print 1
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        print 2
        self.app = Demo2(self.newWindow)
        print 3

class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows)
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect "1" (or maybe "2") to be printed, when `new_window()` method is called. I expect "3" to be printed when `Demo2` was closed! 
But by pressing `button1` I got all three print statements executed.
How can I han handle that?

Comment: sorry for poor wording ...

Comment: the main goal is the using second windows to manage some information forms...

Comment: @BasicWolf, I know "Why does that happen?". I don't know how to manage that...!

Comment: tnx for grammar fixing. I didn't ask "Why". I need to know how to handle events.

Comment: any other comments?

Comment: You may use `wait_window - http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.wait_window-method`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `wait_window` method to wait for the second window to be destroyed before proceeding to the next statement in the first window.

I have modified your code to make it work. Hope it helps -

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Demo1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'New Window', width = 25, command = self.new_window)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
    def new_window(self):
        print 1
        # self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        print 2
        self.app = Demo2(self).display_window()
        print 3

class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = tk.Toplevel(master)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.master.destroy)
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def display_window(self):
        self.master.wait_window()
        return 0

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```